# How to require that a GitHub invite can only be accepted by user with email address that matches corporate domain?

Tags: github, owasp

I am trying to add a new user (new employee) to our GitHub organisation. In doing so, I would like to follow the OWASP recommendations:

https://owasp.org/www-project-top-10-ci-cd-security-risks/CICD-SEC-02-Inadequate-Identity-And-Access-Management

In particular, to:

> Prevent employees from using their **personal email addresses**, or any
> address which belongs to a domain not owned and managed by the
> organization, against the **SCM**, CI, or any other CI/CD platform.

Following this GitHub documentation, I have invited this user using their new corporate email address:

https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-membership-in-your-organization/inviting-users-to-join-your-organization

What puzzles me is that they were able to accept the invitation using their personal GitHub account, which has a different email address to the one I invited. Yet, the documentation above includes:

> Note: If you use an email address for the invitation, the invitee will
> only be able to accept the invitation if the email address matches
> with a verified email address associated with the invitee's personal
> account on GitHub.

Am I misunderstanding something? I know I can just remove their non-corporate email account and invite them again, asking them to be sure to use the corporate one next time. I just thought it would be easier to follow OWASP recommendations, particularly when the GitHub documentation seems to indicate this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: _"**a** verified email address"_ - they can have more than one on the account.

Answer (score 1):

A Github user account can have multiple verified email addresses.

Their corporate email address is one of them, but not the primary one.

Comment: You are right, they had added their corporate email address to their existing, personal GitHub account and so were able to accept the invite. I asked them to remove the corporate email address, and they lost access to the GitHub repo. They created a new GitHub account with the corporate email address, which I invited again, and now they can access the repo in a manner that's a bit more in line with the OWASP recommendations.